# Find row position of some user based on conditions

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project in which I need some help regarding fetching the position of some user based on some criteria. I am showing my query with some example database and table.

For example, I have a database in which there is a table named **users**.

In the **users**, there are 3 fields.

1. id
2. users
3. status

I am using the following query to get the row-position of all user if their status=1 using the following query:

```
SELECT
    @a:=@a+1 as serial_no, username
FROM users
    JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0) a
WHERE status=1;
```

But, I want to get the position of specific user using username field. e.g:username="user3".

But when I run the below query, It returns me that this username exists on 1st position as the serial_no.

```
SELECT
    @a:=@a+1 as serial_no, username
FROM users
    JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0) a
WHERE status=1 AND username="user3";
```

I have created the below SQL Fiddle, so you can help me in an easier way.

https://dbfiddle.uk/QsXF0mBh

Thanks Everyone for your help.

Here is the Updated Link If anyone want to get such kind of results:

https://dbfiddle.uk/mDVjq_Bl

Comment: On modern RDBMS you can use window functions: https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/428f7c14c49d9a0f5d91b759f8f5e38e/

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Bro, this is telling me that user3 is at position:4 but its actually at position:3 if status=1

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/MxxHmd81 fixed from @SlavaRozhnev comment

Comment: @John Doe, Please look updated link with condition: https://sqlize.online/s/9W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the row number, you need to postpone filtering the rows until after they have been numbered:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @a:=@a+1 as serial_no, username
    FROM users
        JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0) a
    WHERE status=1
) AS t
WHERE t.username='user3';
```

The same will be true if you try to use the ROW_NUMBER() window function.

Note this creates a temporary table for the rows matching in the subquery.